# apply margin to inner div and still inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and inner div. I want to give the inner div a margin and still be inside the parent div.

This is the code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ANy `<div>` is a "block" element. It means it will take the full width of its parent by default. If you remove `width: 100%;` from the inner div, you will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the the results in two possible ways:

1. Remove the width from the .inner-container

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>
```

2. Or, add padding to the main-container

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the better way of doing this is by removing margin from inner-container and giving padding 1rem to the main-container, but if you want to do in the same way as you did, then remove width 100% from inner-container, it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Width Property from inner-container and you will get your desired output. [image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can not be achieved unless you change the width.

There are options which accommodate for the border and padding when setting width for a div. That property is called `box-sizing`.

You can omit the width property and divs **`width` + margin** is automatically as big as the parent. (This is width:auto.)

You can use calc() too, but it has the same effect.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: blue;
  
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem)
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>
```